# Insert items in DynamoDB from Snowflake via Glue

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue

Currently I'm working on a script that query data from Snowflake and need it to insert into a DDB table in a glue script.
I can query easily from Snowflake using [the snowflake connector](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-snowflake-home.html). My table looks like this:
[image: Table example]
with the following DynamicFrame schema:

```
root
|-- "customer_id": string
|-- "non_personalized": string
|-- "emalta1": string
|-- "emalta2": string
|-- "emalta3": string
```

(the important is customer_id string field, the others are just auxiliary fields that I will eventuallt turn into dict/struct/array)

where my DDB PK would be customer_id and the other fields would be just any object (usually jsons or arrays).

I have tried:

- Insert the DynamicFrame loaded from snowflake directly into DDB like [shown here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb)
- Saving the DynamicFrame to S3, loading a "json dynamic frame from S3" (like [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-create-sample-dynamic-frame-from-options) (the schema looks like the same above) and trying to write to ddb.
- Transforming the DynamicFrame to pandas, transforming it to json and serializing it in a DDB json format (like

  `{'M': {'"customer_id"': {'S': '79075d7c7276e61df7ca6615986f7d05464995245d3f9155f60467c0cb195cf1'}, '"non_personalized"': {'S': "{'Em Alta1': ['loja1', 'loja2', 'loja3']` )

  and returning it to DynamicFrame and passing it to DDB connector.
  The Schema looks like:

```
    |-- "customer_id": map
    |    |-- keyType: string
    |    |-- valueType: string
    |-- "non_personalized": map
    |    |-- keyType: string
    |    |-- valueType: string
    |-- "emalta1": map
    |    |-- keyType: string
    |    |-- valueType: string
    |-- "emalta2": map
    |    |-- keyType: string
    |    |-- valueType: string
    |-- "emalta3": map
    |    |-- keyType: string
    |    |-- valueType: string
```

None of the options worked and always gave me the following error:

```
An error occurred while calling o122.pyWriteDynamicFrame. The provided key element does not match the schema (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: L7ASM29EH86UQBMKLL5KUF61VBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG; Proxy: null)
```

I have seen that the connector seems to have options ([one](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-unnest_ddb_json) and [two](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-relationalize)) to work from DDB to relational table. How can I do the opposite effectively?

My full code for the first bullet point is as follows:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
import pandas as pd
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
## @params: [JOB_NAME]
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])

sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)

connection_type="snowflake"
connection_options={
        "connectionName": "teste-snowflake",
        #"dbtable": '"fake_data"',
        "sfDatabase": '"db_dev_data"',
        "sfSchema": '"tmp"',
        "sfWarehouse": "DBT_WH",
        "query": 'select * from "db_dev_data"."tmp"."fake_data" limit 200'
}
snowflake_read = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(connection_type ,connection_options)

print('DF snowflake schema')
print(snowflake_read.printSchema())

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=snowflake_read,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={"dynamodb.output.tableName": "teste-glue-snowflake",
        #"dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)
print("Finalizou")

job.commit()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you read into a DynamicFrame, can you show me the output of printSchema? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame-printSchema

Answer (score 0):

From my initial assumption, I believe your data to be the wrong shape for DynamoDB. Based on what you shared:

```
{'M': {'"customer_id"': {'S': '79075d7c7276e61df7ca6615986f7d05464995245d3f9155f60467c0cb195cf1'}, '"non_personalized"': {'S': "{'Em Alta1': ['loja1', 'loja2', 'loja3']
```

You can see here the entire item sits within a map, denoted by `M`, which should not be the case. The correct shape to store in DynamoDB would have `customer_id` at the top level:

```
{'customer_id': {'S': '79075d7c7276e61df7ca6615986f7d05464995245d3f9155f60467c0cb195cf1'}, 'non_personalized': {'S': "{'Em Alta1': ['loja1', 'loja2', 'loja3']
```

---

I don't have access to Snowflake so I am unable to test for you, but in my mind it should be as simple as this:

```
snowflake_node = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="snowflake",
    connection_options={
        "autopushdown": "on",
        "query": "select * from sales where store='1' and IsHoliday='TRUE'",
        "connectionName": "snowflake-glue-conn",
        "sfDatabase": "databaseName",
        "sfSchema": "schemaName",
        "sfWarehouse": "warehouseName",
    }
)

snowflake_node.printSchema()

glue_context.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=snowflake_node,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "my-table-name",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)

job.commit()
```

Comment: it gives me the same error when I create a dynamic frame with the dict['M'] key, like:
columns "customer_id"; value:  {'S': '79075d7c7276e61df7ca6615986f7d054649952... }, column   "emalta3"; value:  {'S': '[(1, 'loja1'), (2, 'loja2'), (3, 'loja3...

Comment: Can you add the schema of your DynamicFrame to your question?

Comment: edited the question to add schemas.
that example you put there is my first bullet point, gives the error

Comment: Thats not the shape you read directly from snowflake. I need you to read from snowflake and directly print the schema.

Comment: that's the first one, with all strings

Comment: The one with all strings looks good, can you share your complete code, redact anything like passwords etc..

Comment: sure, I will add it just now

Comment: Sorry, clicked to edit on your answer and didn't realize lol

Comment: Your code looks perfect to me. The schema is fine, glue automatically converts it to DynamoDB JSON while writing. What to you see if you do a dyn.toDF().show()

Comment: hmmm very weird. if I put it in spark df and show, it shows the same as the select in snowflake (columns cusotmer id with values and other columns exactly the same)

Comment: could this be a problem with the ddb table then? It is configured as: partition key: customer_id (string). sort key: none. capacity: on demand. class standart. no global or local indexes

Comment: No the table looks fine. Let's try one thing, do a `LIMIT 1` from snowflake, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: same happens. I noticed that my print schema shows a "none" after the schema print, no idea why

Comment: i have noticed also the following error in logs:
23/11/08 22:30:38 ERROR Inbox: Ignoring error
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus
Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus, value: org.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus@255a1b0a)
 - element of array (index: 0)
 - array (class [Lorg.apache.spark.storage.StorageStatus;, size 2)

Comment: That exception im not sure on. Do you have additional code that your executing that you haven't shared?

Comment: Another thing to try, may be my final guess as I'm unable to test, is to set the `keep_column_case` parameter in the snowflake read, it may be forcing customer_id to uppercase.

Comment: I dont have any additional code running. I didnt find how to set that, but trying to write on a table with uppercase customer_id fails with same error =\ also tried other snowflake table with no success

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was with the columnn names.
In snowflake, the table columns names are in lowercase.
So,

```
"query": 'select * from "db_dev_data"."tmp"."fake_data" '
```

game the the column `"customer_id"` and not `customer_id`.

For me to accomplish my goal:

- or I'd have to work with uppercase:
  `select "customer_id" as customer_id` and have my DDB table with the uppercase name (I didn't found a way to select the column name in lowercase, since adding `as "customer_id"` in the select kept the double quotes in name.
- or use the `rename_field('"customer_id"', 'customer_id')` dynamic frame method to rename my columns.

After removing the quotes from the columns names, everything worked fine.